# $sample do not return the specified number of documents

Tags: mongodb

From the doc of [$sample](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/#pipe._S_sample)

> $sample
>
> New in version 3.2.
>
> Randomly selects the specified number of documents from its input.

```
> db.version()
3.4.3

> db.docs.count({'tag': 'Foo'})
27659


> db.docs.aggregate([
    {$sample: {'size': 10}},
    {$match: {'tag': 'Foo'}},
]) // <- randomly returns from 0 to 4 documents. Why ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregation pipeline goes to every stage and passes the result to next stage. In your case:

You are first getting random 10 sample documents and then filtering those 10 from match query. Hence you are getting random number from 10.

You should have match query first and then sample.

```
db.docs.aggregate([
    {$match: {'tag': 'Foo'}},
    {$sample: {'size': 10}}  
]);
```

Also to get 10 sample documents, there should be minimum 10 documents matching the match query. Otherwise it will b less than 10 so don't worry if it happens.